# Positioning elements in a half-circle in correct way around Blue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this guy Blue (the blue character) and I want to add some elements in the half-circle around him.

each element is a container of an image and a span of text that should be positioned below the image.

I have tried this but as you see the elements rotate this way and each of spans not positioned correctly.

How can I do this?

```css
.blueAnime {
  width: 30vw;
  height: auto;
}

.blueContainer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width:100%;
  padding-top:600px;
}



.coins {
  width: 5vw;
  height: auto;
}

.circle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -15px;
}

.one { transform: rotate(-0deg) translate(40vw); }
.two { transform: rotate(-20deg) translate(40vw); }
.three { transform: rotate(-40deg) translate(40vw); }
.four { transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(40vw); }
.five { transform: rotate(-80deg) translate(40vw); }
.six { transform: rotate(-100deg) translate(40vw); }
.seven { transform: rotate(-120deg) translate(40vw); }
.eight { transform: rotate(-140deg) translate(40vw); }
.nine { transform: rotate(-160deg) translate(40vw); }
.ten { transform: rotate(-180deg) translate(40vw); }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body> 

<div class="blueContainer">
    <img class="blueAnime" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/blue.png">

    <div class="circle one">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle two">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle three">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle four">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle five">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle six">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle seven">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle eight">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle nine">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle ten">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Scroll down to see the Blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's set up the img and span correctly. A single `.circle` element should look like this:

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.circle > img {
  display: block;
  width: 30px; height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle four">
  <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
  <span>text below</span>
</div>
```

Now that we have a single `.circle` element set up we can define many of them, and rotate them appropriately:

```css
.blueAnime { width: 30vw; height: auto; }
.blueContainer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width:100%;
  padding-top:300px;
}
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.circle > img {
  display: block;
  width: 30px; height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.one { transform: rotate(-0deg) translate(40vw); }
.two { transform: rotate(-20deg) translate(40vw); }
.three { transform: rotate(-40deg) translate(40vw); }
.four { transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(40vw); }
.five { transform: rotate(-80deg) translate(40vw); }
.six { transform: rotate(-100deg) translate(40vw); }
.seven { transform: rotate(-120deg) translate(40vw); }
.eight { transform: rotate(-140deg) translate(40vw); }
.nine { transform: rotate(-160deg) translate(40vw); }
.ten { transform: rotate(-180deg) translate(40vw); }
```

```html
<div class="blueContainer">
    <img class="blueAnime" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/blue.png">

    <div class="circle one"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle two"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle three"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle four"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle five"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle six"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle seven"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle eight"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle nine"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle ten"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>

</div>
```

Note that the `.circle` elements still become rotated - we want them all exactly level, as a non-rotated element would be. We can achieve this by using `rotate(n)` before *and after* the `translate` property! Matrix operations produce different results depending on their order. Or goal here will be to "unrotate" the `.circle` element after translating and rotating it. Essentially the first rotation both visually rotates the `.circle`, and influences the direction of the upcoming transform. The second rotation, however, only visually "unrotates" the `.circle`, and since it is not followed by any transform operation, the center of the `.circle` will stay put.

```css
.blueAnime { width: 30vw; height: auto; }
.blueContainer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 300px;
}
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.circle > img {
  display: block;
  width: 30px; height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.one { transform: rotate(-0deg) translate(40vw) rotate(0deg); }
.two { transform: rotate(-20deg) translate(40vw) rotate(20deg); }
.three { transform: rotate(-40deg) translate(40vw) rotate(40deg); }
.four { transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(40vw) rotate(60deg); }
.five { transform: rotate(-80deg) translate(40vw) rotate(80deg); }
.six { transform: rotate(-100deg) translate(40vw) rotate(100deg); }
.seven { transform: rotate(-120deg) translate(40vw) rotate(120deg); }
.eight { transform: rotate(-140deg) translate(40vw) rotate(140deg); }
.nine { transform: rotate(-160deg) translate(40vw) rotate(160deg); }
.ten { transform: rotate(-180deg) translate(40vw) rotate(180deg); }
```

```html
<div class="blueContainer">
    <img class="blueAnime" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/blue.png">

    <div class="circle one"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle two"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle three"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle four"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle five"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle six"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle seven"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle eight"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle nine"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>
    <div class="circle ten"><img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png"><span>Text below</span></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Props for transforms before and after!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.blueAnime {
  width: 30vw;
  height: auto;
}

.blueContainer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width:100%;
  padding-top:600px;
  position:relative;
}



.coins {
  width: 5vw;
  height: auto;
}

.circle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 30%;
    margin: -15px;
}

.one { transform: rotate(-0deg) translate(40vw); }
.two { transform: rotate(-20deg) translate(40vw); }
.three { transform: rotate(-40deg) translate(40vw); }
.four { transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(40vw); }
.five { transform: rotate(-80deg) translate(40vw); }
.six { transform: rotate(-100deg) translate(40vw); }
.seven { transform: rotate(-120deg) translate(40vw); }
.eight { transform: rotate(-140deg) translate(40vw); }
.nine { transform: rotate(-160deg) translate(40vw); }
.ten { transform: rotate(-180deg) translate(40vw); }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body> 

<div class="blueContainer">
    <img class="blueAnime" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/blue.png">

    <div class="circle one">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle two">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle three">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle four">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle five">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle six">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle seven">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle eight">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle nine">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

    <div class="circle ten">
        <img class="coins" src="https://langfox.ir/pictures/coins.png">
        <span>This is going to be below each image</span>
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Add `position:relative;` to **blueContainer** class

```
.circle {    
    top: 80%;
    left: 30%;
}
```

please change `top and left` as you want

Comment: The issue is the rotation of elements!